# Is there any software package tracking Pauli errors in stabilizing circuits with GUI?

Tags: programming, error-correction

I want to track the Pauli errors propagating in stabilizer circuits like surface code. I wonder whether there is any developed package that can do this elegantly. It will be better if it has GUI that I can throw Pauli errors in conveniently.